# Something I could not figure out in my exam today

Tags: ruby

How can you use this class to print "foo" but not "foobar"? You cannot edit the class.

```
class Test

    def foo
        puts "foo"
        foobar
    end 

    def foobar
        puts "foobar"
    end

end
```

**Edit:** I just came up with a solution where you create a subclass to `Test` and override `foo` so that it just prints "foo".

Comment: Make sure to add your solution as an answer!

Comment: I'm not sure if `SubTest.new.foo` qualifies. It sounds to me that `foo` has to be invoked on an instance of `Test`. (btw, rather than redefining `foo` in the subclass, you could define a stub method `def foobar; end` in the subclass, but that doesn't solve the possible problem I mentioned.)

Comment: Hmm. You're probably right that using a subclass is permitted. It's probably what the setter of the question had in mind. As @tibsar suggests, you should post an answer.

Comment: I don”t think this question is answerable as it stands, we don’t know what the exam is looking for. There are many ways you could “use this class”, e.g. would `Test.new.send :puts, "foo"` be acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following.

```
class Test
  def foo
    puts "foo"
    foobar
  end 
  def foobar
    puts "foobar"
  end
end

Test.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:foo, :foobar] 
Test.new.foo
  # foo
  # foobar
```

Create an alias of `:foobar`

```
Test.class_eval { alias_method :old_foobar, :foobar }
  #=> Test 
Test.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:foo, :foobar, :old_foobar]
Test.new.old_foobar
  # foobar
Test.new.foobar
  # foobar
```

Create a stub method `:foobar`.

```
Test.class_eval { define_method(:foobar) {} }
  #=> :foobar
```

Try it.

```
Test.new.foo
  # foo
```

**Clean-up**

Restore the original `:foobar`.

```
Test.class_eval { alias_method :foobar, :old_foobar }
  #=> Test
Test.new.foo
  # foo
  # foobar
```

Remove `:old_foobar`.

```
Test.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:foo, :foobar, :old_foobar] 
Test.class_eval { remove_method(:old_foobar) }
  #=> Test 
Test.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:foo, :foobar]
```

**Note**

```
Test.class_eval { alias_method :old_foobar, :foobar }
```

produces the same alias `:old_foobar` as does

```
class Test
  alias_method :old_foobar, :foobar
end
```

but it does it dynamically.

Alternatively, one can write

```
Test.send(:alias_method, :old_foobar, :foobar)
```

but not

```
Test.alias_method :old_foobar, :foobar
```

because `:alias_method` is private.

These comments also apply to the other two uses of `class_eval`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit the class.

```
test = Test.new
test.foo
# => foo
# => foobar
```

But you can edit the object instantiated from the `Test` class

```
class << test
  def foobar
  end
end
test.foo
# foo
```

for more information, you can google "singleton methods".